# How to copy hyperlinks using typescript to clipboard and gmail message

Tags: typescript, hyperlink, gmail, clipboard

I'm trying to create & copy the following hyperlink-text list into the clipboard using Typescript:

- [Google](https://google.com)
- [IBM](https://ibm.com)
- [Amazon](https://amazon.com)

I have been trying to use the **clipboard API (Typescript)** to copy HTML-based data such as hyperlinks to **Gmail** but so far without success. Do you have any suggestions on how I should approach this? I tried to use `navigator.clipboard.write`, but it didn't work for me with HTML. I only managed to send a plain text with `navigator.clipboard.writeText`